# Is there a way to "Answer call" Google Hangouts from a script?

Tags: google-hangouts

I wrote a Bash script to help me answer Hangouts incoming phone calls.

When an incoming call rings Hangouts, I click the script launcher.
The script then switches sound from speakers to headphones.
Then I make three more clicks to answer the call:

1. open Chrome browser
2. open Hangouts tab
3. click "Answer call"

Is there a way the script could also "Answer call" the Google Hangouts for me?
Thus saving me 3 clicks.

I am on Linux Fedora 27.

Comment: Wrote a script in what? It interacts with chrome, how?

Comment: It's a Bash script.  I don't know how to interact with Chrome.  That's why I am asking.